# Display drupal node edit preview title instead of just "Preview"

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to change the node preview title to be displayed instead of just "Preview"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to solve your problem in your custom module

```
/**
 * implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter
 * the form id that will build the node preview is page_node_form
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 */
function yourmodulename_form_page_node_form_alter( $form, $form_state ){
    if( !empty( $form_state['node']->in_preview ) ){
        // security hint: do not pass the PASS_THROUGH param to the drupal_set_title
        // because the node title may contain some xss. Without this parameter the
        // drupal_set_title will check for xss and remove them if present
        drupal_set_title(t('Preview') . ' ' . $form['#node']->title );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @lastYorsh and re Pass_THROUGH (it was like this in core :D ), I tried it but it's not changing the title yet. I even used `function nodepreviewtitle_form_page_node_form_alter( $form, $form_state ){ dpm($form_state);` but i didn't get the variables printed out with devel hence I'm concerned it's not being triggered for some reason.

Comment: I found the title definition in `function node_preview($node) {` (within /node/node.pages.inc)
Do we need to adjust the function name/hook to trigger correctly?
How can I identify that I need to use "_form_page_node" before "_form_alter"?

Comment: have you cleared the drupal cache after you have added the yourmodulename_form_page_node_form_alter function?

Comment: yes, cache cleared. Not sure it helps but used a custom module to display dsm($form_id) which shows two: 
faq_node_form & search_form. I want to apply this though to all kind of content, not just faq_node :) 
I can see "op" value contains "Preview" in that node.

Comment: I take that "_form_page_node" is supposed to relate to all type of node edit previews? I tried `function nodepreviewtitle_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state ){` which actually worked, triggering the if condition. But is this still the right way?

Comment: The function yourmodulename_form_page_node_form_alter will react to the form with id
page_node_form. This form is created by drupal when you edit a node from the administrative page
at this url: <drupal_url>?q=node/<node_id>/edit
at the bottom of this page there is the "Preview" button.
Perhaps I've misunderstood what you need :)

Comment: Yes exactly that, ok, I just figured it out, as per earlier comment in my case it actually used **faq_node_form** which i tried and now works :)
Thanks again lastYorsh, I learned lots, you rock!

Answer (score -2):

Here how to hack core to modify the title (quick and easy way) but better would be to override via a custom module (perhaps somebody else can post please).

In /modules/node/node.pages.inc add `$node->title` within     `drupal_set_title(t('Preview'), PASS_THROUGH);`

like so:

```
// Display a preview of the node.
    if (!form_get_errors()) {
      $cloned_node->in_preview = TRUE;
      $output = theme('node_preview', array('node' => $cloned_node));
      unset($cloned_node->in_preview);
    }
    drupal_set_title(t('Preview: '.$node->title), PASS_THROUGH);
```

Comment: Hacking Drupal core is always a bad idea, the other answer is ok.

Comment: @EricLavault I know, that's why I said better is a custom module, thanks :)